# 'Exception has occurred: ImportError DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.' exception often occurs in my VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

This error occurs when I open up my VS Code and execute the code or sometimes when I push debugging button.

But the strange thing is that It doesn't show up again if I restart the debugging mode.

Why does this kind of thing happen in this arbitrary way?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Antonio\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.3.6558\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 45, in <module>
    main(ptvsdArgs)
  File "c:\Users\Antonio\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.3.6558\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 391, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\Antonio\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.3.6558\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 272, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='__main__')
  File "C:\Users\Antonio\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Users\Antonio\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\Antonio\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\Antonio\Documents\aits\simulation\simulatorW.py", line 4, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\Antonio\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\Antonio\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Can you provide the traceback or error details? Otherwise the best guess is you have a corrupted install.

Comment: @BrettCannon, Thank you so much, I added the detail. Would you spare a minute to check this??

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing some MKL-related module. I would try re-installing numpy to try and get that back.

Comment: I reinstalled numpy and wait for that situation to occur again. I really appreciate your help. Let me have a moment to check :)